# ExtJS ComboBox if forceselection true keep typed value

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a combobox with force selection true. when user types an arbitrary value it clears the value when validating. I need to know how to keep the invalid value that user entered while displaying its invalid. Like alternative forceSelection.

Thanks. Hopes an immediate help.

Comment: That's the whole point of using `forceSelection`. If the user doesn't enter a valid value, it will select the last value.

Comment: Couldn't I keep the invalid value with error message without having force selection config.

Comment: **Found a result for this and it works perfectly.**
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885503/extjs-findexact-and-custom-validator-bug

Comment: I had a similar issue with multiple ComboBoxes sharing the same store, for solution see:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35198226/1749200

Answer (score 1):

**Found a result for this and it works perfectly.**

[ExtJS findExact() and custom validator bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885503/extjs-findexact-and-custom-validator-bug)